# Search button is not getting handled in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on search button with below html tab but not able to handled in selenium webdriver with java. Tried code is aslo writeen below.

HTML Tag:-

```
<input class="btn btn_search_secondary searchContent2 leBtnDisable" name="abc13600000000" value="Select" onclick="javascript:showBUBoxy('buId','selectClassBu',true);javascript:showHideErrorBussiness();" type="button">
```

Written Code:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Select' and @type='button']")).click();
```

Comment: HTML Tag:- <input class="btn btn_search_secondary searchContent2 leBtnDisable" name="abc13600000000" value="Select" onclick="javascript:showBUBoxy('buId','selectClassBu',true);javascript:showHideErrorBussiness();" type="button">

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: "No such element found" exception encounters

Comment: Is the button inside an `<ifarme>` tag?

Comment: How about trying xpath as  `//input[@name="abc13600000000"]`

Comment: Can you please provide URL in which ur working . Would be more help

Comment: But my guess you have copied the wrong `HTML` tag. The one you copied is disabled. Thanks

Comment: Did you try this locator using Firepath? Using firepath you can see whether this element is available in top window or in any iFrame.

Comment: No this button is not in iframe

Comment: <input id="selectClassBu" class="textField big box3 required" name="selBU" readonly="readonly" onblur="myBlur(this);" onfocus="myFocus(this);" placeholder="Select Business Unit" type="text">
<input class="btn btn_search_secondary searchContent2 leBtnDisable" name="abc13600000000" value="Select" onclick="javascript:showBUBoxy('buId','selectClassBu',true);javascript:showHideErrorBussiness();" type="button">
                                                                                                  This is related HTML tag

Comment: //input[@name="abc13600000000"] is not working because this name value is used in other tag too

Comment: NoSuchElementFound exception is very common and has been answered many times here, search those threads and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here in my side this button by your given snippet is accessible with cssselector using this code `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn_search_secondary")).click();`
But i can see there is some "leBtnDisable" class is applied what is this? Please make sure in your code due this class is button disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

As in the html tag there is a name attribute and mostly the name attributes are unique so you can use `//input[@name="abc13600000000"]` but you have written it still not working so it would be better if share the url.